# Google Analytics - page_title reporting does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, single-page-application, gtag.js

This code had worked for me for a long time to report the title of the web page to google analytics.  Overnight, it stopped working and I'm trying to figure out how to make it work again.

The code looks like this:

index.html file:

```
 <head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>World Peace Catalyst Fund</title> 
 <base href="/">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

 <!--  Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics  -->

 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GTAG_ID"></script>

 <script>

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 async function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
 await gtag('js', new Date());

  // gtag('config', 'Google-Ads-Tag'); 
  await gtag('config', 'Google-Analytics-Tag' );//{ 'send_page_view': false}

  </script>

  </head>
```

appcomponent.ts

```
 constructor(public router: Router){



  this.router.events.subscribe(async event => {
   if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {   
   await gtag('config','Google-Anlaytics-Tag',{page_title: 
    event.urlAfterRedirects});//'send_page_view': true,
    console.log("this is a test");
    console.log("page_title:" + event.urlAfterRedirects);
   }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I need to send the conversion event as a manual event instead of a gtag config event.

```
  gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    page_title: event.urlAfterRedirects 

   });
```

That code snippet sends the page I am viewing to the google analytics.